# Code halts unexpectedly on backend of my wix site

Tags: javascript, velo

I wrote an asynchronous function which is supposed to check if a given url returns a '200' from a get and otherwise wait a few seconds to try again a limited number of times. The code works just fine when I run it in my computer using node but when I transfer it to backend it only checks for the site once and then immediately stops when receiving an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
async function wait(url,delay=10000,attp=3){
 let t0 = new Date(Date.now());
 let attempts = 0;
    console.log('starting...');
 async function check(){
 if(attempts<attp){
            console.log('ATTEMPTS: ',attempts);
 return await request.get(url).on('error',
 async function(err){
                console.log('ERROR: ',err);
                attempts+=1;
 return await setTimeout(()=>{check()},delay);
            }).on('response',
 async function(response){
 if(response.statusCode===200){
 let t1 = new Date(Date.now());
                    wixData.insert('pagSeguroTimeStats', { 'time': (t1 - t0) / 1000. });
 return '200';
                }else{
                    attempts+=1;
                    console.log('not 200');
 return await setTimeout(()=>{check()},delay);
                }
            });
        }else{
 return '404';
        }
    }
 return check();
}
```

Comment: You have a lot of weird `async` / `await` usage here. It's only meant to be used with promises, and you're using it within callback functions, and `setTimeout`. Hope that helps.

Comment: My intention was to make some sort of recursive asynchronous function that would repeatedly check if the url returns a 'ok'. I'll see if I can reduce the usage of async/await although the code works just fine on my computer and not in wix. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there is a limit to how much time a backend function can run. From the Wix Code [forum](https://www.wix.com/code/home/forum/community-feature-request/adjustable-timeout-for-backend-functions), it seems that the limit is 14 seconds, although this doesn't look like an official number from Wix.

Comment: Oh boy, I didn't know that... I guess I'm gonna have to find another way. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

The 14 second limit only applies to web functions.

Time
Wix allows web modules called from the frontend, HTTP functions, and router hooks to run for up to 14 seconds. This limitation applies to both free and premium sites. Any of these methods that take longer than 14 seconds receives a 504 response code. Note that after 14 seconds the code might still execute, but the connection to the client is closed so the results do not appear in the frontend. This error message appears in your log:
/backend/.js(w)/ timed out because it exceeded the maximum execution time.

I've got a .js function that just stop, and I get no error or anything.